# How to get Specific chars from string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html, can't use "attr", so according to me only substring is the option to get specific data from following html:

```
<video poster="images/IMG_4979.jpg" controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="video/IMG_4979.mp4"></source></video>
```

Actually, i want to get **poster** tag's data. i tried by following way, but it always return wrong data.

```
 var pswp.currItem.html = '<video poster="images/IMG_4979.jpg" controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="video/IMG_4979.mp4"></source></video>'
 var misc = pswp.currItem.html.substring(0, pswp.currItem.html.indexOf('controls'));
alert(misc)
```

i have created "**pswp.currItem.html**" as var here so that it could be easy to understand, but it is coming from this "pswp.currItem.html" object, on which attr is not working.

please help me how can i get poster tag's data. (image path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the string to a JQuery object.

I have broken down the single steps for you for easy understanding.

```js
// this is your HTML string
var html_str = '<video poster="images/IMG_4979.jpg" controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="video/IMG_4979.mp4"></source></video>';

// now we create a JQuery object from your string
var $jq_obj = $(html_str);

// now we can access the JQuery object as if it were part of the DOM
var poster = $jq_obj.attr('poster');

// log the attribute
console.log(poster);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work if the pswp.currItem.html string format stays the same.

```
var poster_image_path = pswp.currItem.html.split('"')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attr` attribute could not work on your custom object `pswp.currItem.html`, but it surely will work if your wrap this string with jQuery:

```
var poster = $(pswp.currItem.html).attr('poster');
```

Answer (score -1):

Why can you not use attr? Why are you trying to assign a value to an object?

```
var posterTag = $('video').attr('poster');
```